# Processing/Java: adding/appending String array item to String + type detection

Tags: java, processing

i'm working with a dataset in the form of several directories of *.csv (semi-comma separated, actually, for some reason) files, which i would like to process and add to a mysql db. yesterday, mr. data converter came to my attention (praise twitter!) and a few tweaks to the code allowed me to use the semi-comma delimited text, via copy+paste.

this is nice, but i wondered if i could port the code (javascript) to processing so that i could recursively go through the files and add tables. while most of it is working (the syntax at least), a couple of issues are keeping me from actually testing this on the bunch of files i mentioned above.

below is the code i have thus far (apart from SQLibrary and boilerplate code for loading the files), and below that, the questions.

```
String newLine = "\n";
String indent = " ";
String toMySql(String[] lines, String tableName, String[] columnNames, String[] columnTypes, String indent, String newLine) {
  String outputText = "";
  int rowCount = lines.length;
  int columnCount = columnNames.length;
  //begin render loop
  outputText += "CREATE TABLE "+tableName+" (" + newLine;
  outputText += indent+"id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,"+newLine;
  for (int i=0; i < columnCount; i++) {
    String dataType = "VARCHAR(255)";
    if ((columnTypes[i].equals("int"))||(columnTypes[i].equals("float"))) {
      dataType = columnTypes[i].toUpperCase();
    };
    outputText += indent+""+columnNames[i]+" "+dataType;
    if (i < columnCount - 1) {
      outputText += ",";
    }
    outputText += newLine;
  }
  outputText += ");" + newLine;
  outputText += "INSERT INTO "+tableName+" "+newLine+indent+"(";
  for (int i=0; i < columnCount; i++) {
    outputText += columnNames[i];
    if (i < columnCount - 1) {
      outputText += ",";
    }
  }
  outputText += ") "+newLine+"VALUES "+newLine;
  for (int i=0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    outputText += indent+"(";
    for (int j=0; j < columnCount; j++) {
      if ((columnTypes[j] == "int")||(columnTypes[j] == "float")) {
        // outputText += lines[i][j] || "null";
      }
      else {
        // outputText += "'"+( lines[i][j] || "" )+"'";
      }
      if (j < columnCount - 1) outputText += ",";
    }
    outputText += ")";
    if (i < rowCount - 1) outputText += ","+newLine;
  }
  outputText += ";";
  return outputText;
}
String[] getColumnNames(String[] lines, String delimiter) {
  return split(lines[0], delimiter);
}
//test columns for number data type
String[] getColumnTypes(String[] lines, String delimiter) {
  int columnCount = split(lines[0], delimiter).length;
  String[] columnTypes = new String[columnCount];
  int numRowsToTest = columnCount;
  float threshold = 0.5;
  for (int i=0; i < columnCount; i++) {
    int floatCount = 0;
    int intCount = 0;
    for (int j=0; j < numRowsToTest; j++) {
      /*if (CSVParser.isNumber(lines[j][i])) {
       intCount++;
       if (String(lines[j][i]).indexOf(".") > 0) {
       floatCount++;
       }
       }*/
    }
    if ((intCount / numRowsToTest) > threshold) {
      if (floatCount > 0) {
        columnTypes[i] = "float";
      }
      else {
        columnTypes[i] = "int";
      }
    }
    else {
      columnTypes[i] = "string";
    }
  }
  return columnTypes;
}
boolean isNumber (String token) {
  /*if( (token.equals(null)) || isNaN( new Number(string) ) ) {
   return false;
   } */
  return true;
}
```

first up...

**issue 1**

```
for (int i=0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    outputText += indent+"(";
    for (int j=0; j < columnCount; j++) {
      if ((columnTypes[j] == "int")||(columnTypes[j] == "float")) {
        // HERE!
        // outputText += lines[i][j] || "null";
      }
      else {
         // AND HERE!
        // outputText += "'"+( lines[i][j] || "" )+"'";
      }
      if (j < columnCount - 1) outputText += ",";
    }
    outputText += ")";
    if (i < rowCount - 1) outputText += ","+newLine;
  }
```

the commented lines return a "the type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String" error. if i'm referring to an item/index of a two-dimensional String array, is that not a String itself?

does this have anything to do with using the "+=" operator, instead of "concat()" method in String, or something of the sort? or with using a single string ("outputText") for the whole mysql output, instead of a String array?

**issue 2**

```
boolean isNumber (String token) {
  /*if( (token.equals(null)) || isNaN( new Number(string) ) ) {
   return false;
   } */
  return true;
}
```

this is just plain wrong, i know. how would one go about writing a method in Processing for detecting if a String is a number?

thanks for reading,
bernardo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue 1:**

Your array lines is a `String[]` not a `String[][]`, so `lines[i][j]` does not make sense. I think you should just use `lines[i]`.

Also note you could use [String.valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29) instead of doing `|| "null"` yourself, i.e.

```
outputText += String.valueOf(lines[i]);
```

**Issue 2:**

You could use this:

```
boolean isNumber (String token) {
  try {
    Integer.parseInt(token);
    return true;
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

If the token is a formatted number, (e.g. using localized decimal separator) then you could parse with a [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) instead and catch ParseException.

Comment: *slaps head* thanks, marking this at best answer because it points out my crass mistake. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Issue1:
`outputText += String.valueOf(lines[i][j]);`

`outputText += "'" + String.valueOf(lines[i][j])+ "'";`

Issue2 :

```
boolean isNumber (String token) { 
  try {
      Integer.parseInt(token);
  } catch(Exception e) {
    return false;
  }      
  return true;
}
```